# define my arithmetic function with Prolog?

Tags: swi-prolog

```
sum([],0).
sum([H|T],S) :- sum(T,X),S is X+H.

mean([],0).
mean(L,M) :- sum(L,S),length(L,L1),M is S/L1.
:-arithmetic_function(mean/1).
when i try 
?- mean([1,2,3,4],X).
```

it replies with

```
X= 2.5 
Yes
```

Now I wanna Use

```
?- X is mean ([1,2,3,4].
```

but it repies with

```
Type error: ERROR: '.'/2: Type error: `[]' expected, found `[2, 3, 4]' ("x" must hold one character)
```

How Can use arithmetic-function with a list?

Comment: You are using here a deprecated, SWI-specific feature

Answer (score 3):

While your code looks like it's on the right track, unfortunately it seems that arbitrary-length lists of numbers **cannot be used** as a parameter (argument) to functions defined to be `arithmetic_function`s, such as your parameter to `mean/1`.

The problem appears related to the fact that, [in SWI-Prolog, `./2` is itself considered to be an arithmetic type](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=./2) in this context.

**Explanation:**

Consider:

```
?- X is 1 + 2 * 3.
X = 7.
```

Because the arithmetic operator `*` has precedence over `+`, this is actually:

```
?- X is (1 + (2 * 3)).
X = 7.
```

Additionally, `+` and `*` are binary infix operators, which can otherwise be written as such:

```
?- X is '+'(1, '*'(2, 3)).
X = 7.
```

Note that here, SWI-Prolog is in fact evaluating the expression tree 'inside-out', the `*` first, then applying the result to the `+` expression. With this in mind, now consider your example:

```
?- X is mean([1,2,3,4]).
```

What SWI-Prolog actually interprets is in fact:

```
?- X is mean('.'(1,[2,3,4])).
```

Now, because `'.'/2` is an arithmetic type, SWI-Prolog evaluates this expression first (like `*` in the example above), but type-checking reveals that it is not of the required pattern `.(+Int,[])`, i.e., lists of length one containing an integer (see the documentation behind the link above). Since `[]` does not equal `[2,3,4]`, the type error you report is raised.

You might also consider trying the following:

```
?- X is mean([1]).
```

What SWI-Prolog actually interprets is in fact:

```
?- X is mean('.'(1,[])).
```

Now, while this is a valid instance of the type pattern `.(+Int,[])`, it is *evaluated* (much in the same way as `*` was evaluated as shown above) to give `1`, as per the semantics of this arithmetic type. The value `1` is then bound to the first input argument of the implementation of `mean/2`, which you'd otherwise want to be the input list.